# How to store the value received through a method in another variable instance?

Tags: json, flutter, statefulwidget, flutter-state, statelesswidget

How to store the value received through a method in another variable instance?

I want to store the value passed to the Statefulwidget in an instance which I am not able to do. This is how I pass the value to the Statefulwidget's method.

```
_MyHomePageState().getprints(state1);
```

But not able to store the data in an instance in the StatefulWidget, Please check the comments to see what is working what is not working

```
var state11;
getprints(var state1){
 
   print("hello");
   print(state1); //this works
   state11 = state1; // this does not works
}
```

How should I save it in an instance in flutter?

Comment: where have you declared state11?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali global variable in the class where the method is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a 'dart' question than a 'flutter' one. So I just tested out the code in [dartpad.dev](https://www.dartpad.dev/)

The thing is, it does get stored in state1. But the thing is, you can't refer to it with another instance cause then that instance will be a newly created instance and will have a different value for state1. The solution?
You can make state11 a static variable and instead of calling the instance, you call it with the class directly. Like this:

```
void main() {
  print(MyHomePageState.state11);     //Line 1
  MyHomePageState().getprints('Some state');
  print(MyHomePageState.state11);     //Line 4
}

class MyHomePageState {
  static var state11;
  getprints(var state1) {
    print("hello");                   //Line 2
    print(state1);                    //Line 3
    state11 = state1; 
  }
}
```

with output as:

```
null
hello
Some state
Some state
```

This ensures that change in value to state1 is reflected across all instances of the class.

Or...
You can store the instance in a variable and then call the variable of that instance.

```
void main() {
  var homePage = MyHomePageState();
  homePage.getprints('Some state');
  print(homePage.state11);            //Line 3
}

class MyHomePageState {
  var state11;
  getprints(var state1) {
    print("hello");                   //Line 1
    print(state1);                    //Line 2
    state11 = state1; 
  }
}
```

with output as:

```
hello
Some state
Some state
```

But since you're using this for a HomePage widget, I'd recommend using the first method.